# stored procedure execution gives different results in SSIS Vs. SSMS

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, ssms, sql-server-profiler

I execute a stored procedure which takes in 7 parameters and returns an integer code. When I run the exec statement, it works perfectly and gives a valid result. But when I run the same using SSIS, I get the exact opposite result of what I am expecting.

I ran the trace on Profiler and saw what was being passed. The values have the correct sequence and correct values. I am not sure what is going on with SSIS execution part.

I verified the data types too and they look good to me. One thing that I noticed on the profiler was that even the integer valued columns were being passed as varchars with single quotes around them. Does that make any difference? Below is what I got from Profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC [dbo].[ProcName] @P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5,@P6,@P7',N'@P1 varchar(6),@P2 nvarchar(9),@P3 datetime2(0),@P4 varchar(1),@P5 varchar(1),@P6 varchar(4),@P7 nvarchar(5)','743290',N'000000034','2018-07-25 00:00:00','2','2','1002',N'Swift'
```

Thanks,
RV

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So this was a mistake on my part. The query that was running on SSMS was running on the primary instance of the cluster where as the SSIS package points to the readonly instance of the cluster.

I was under the impression that the data is the same on these 2 server, but that was my mistake. I started pointing the SSMS version to the readonly instance and it gave the exact same result as I was expecting. Hence closing this out.